# How to setup psycopg2 with Google App Engine PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine, psycopg2

I have an application that is being run on Google's App Engine and I want it to use the associated PostgreSQL database. I'm using psycopg2 to help me with my SQL queries. However I am not sure how I can set up the connection. This is what I currently have:

```
con = psycopg2.connect(
    host=HOST_NAME, # the IP address of the SQL database
    database=DATABASE_NAME, # the name of the database (I'm using the default, so this is "postgres"
    user=USER_NAME, # just the user name that I created
    password=PASSWORD # the password associated to that user
)
```

However, when I try to make a request, I get the error `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out` when creating this connection. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit tricky, but here is what worked for me. I will help you to set up the Quickstart App Engine with psycopg2 and after that you will get the idea.

Use the [Quickstart for Python in the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) documentation to set up and deploy your app.

Use the [Connecting from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine) documentation to connect to your App Engine app to the Cloud SQL Postgre SQL.

I have did slightly modifications in order to make that work:

In `app.yaml` add:

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: [INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:5432
#[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME] = [PROJECT_NAME]:[INSTANCE_ZONE]:[INSTANCE_NAME]
#[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME] can be found at Google Cloud Console Cloud SQL's instance page, under "Instance connection name".
```

In `requirements.txt` add:

```
psycopg2
psycopg2-binary
```

In `main.py` add:

```
@app.route('/connect')
def connect():
    try:
        #host='172.17.0.1' is the defult IP for the docker container that it is being created during the deployment of the App Engine
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='172.17.0.1' password='test'")
        return "Connection was established!"
    except:
        return "I am unable to connect to the database"
```

Use the `gcloud app deploy` command to deploy your app.

After the deployment, use the `gcloud app browse` command to open the app in the browser.

When accessing the link `https://[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/connect`
It should respond with `Connection was established!`

Comment: i tried the steps you stated here but im still getting a connection timeout error. should the `host` be the public IP address of the sql instance or is it always going to be `172.17.0.1`?

Comment: I have tried all the steps above and they worked for me. Yes it is going to be always `172.17.0.1` because you are using the Cloud SQL proxy setup in the `app.yaml` file. Therefore, you have to connect to the default IP address and port of the container that it is being generated by default. I would suggest start the same process again from the beginning, creating a new SQL instance with a new App Engine Python app. And then see the differences  .