# Connect to Postgres on App Engine (Google Cloud) using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, psycopg2, pg8000

I am looking to connect to my PostgresSQL instance using `psycopg2` in a Python app running on App Engine (standard). I have been searching for many days now, but I am unable to find a solution that gives me a way to connect using `psycopg2`. All the solutions (including the one in official documentation) point to a method using `pg8000`.

The reason I am trying to use `psycopg2` as a driver is that I would like to run multiple sql queries in a single transaction, something like:

```
   query = '''
     update table1 set field1 = '2';
     update table2 set field1 = '3';
   '''
   session.run(query)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your your database connexion configuration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup psycopg2 with Google App Engine PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391490/how-to-setup-psycopg2-with-google-app-engine-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 0):

In your question you wrote:

> The reason I am trying to use psycopg2 as a driver is that I would
> like to run multiple sql queries in a single transaction

but from your example it looks like you wanted to execute multiple SQL statements in one call. This [is possible](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#execute-multiple-sql-statements) with pg8000, for example:

```
>>> import pg8000.native
>>>
>>> con = pg8000.native.Connection("postgres", password="cpsnow")
>>>
>>> statements = "SELECT 5; SELECT 'Erich Fromm';"
>>>
>>> con.run(statements)
[[5], ['Erich Fromm']]
```